# Why my DBN's hidden layer outputs are all 1's?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

I use the [Deeplearning.net DBN codes](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/) to train my data sets. However, the predicted values are all identical. I then printed out the inputs of each hidden layer and its weight matrix. What could go wrong?

```
predicting results for test set
hidden layer input __str__ = [[ 24.19000053  23.70000076  23.84000015 ...,   0.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 16.93000031  16.71999931  16.88999939 ...,   1.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 19.77000046  18.73999977  18.75       ...,   0.           0.           0.        ]
 ..., 
 [ 36.84000015  36.11000061  36.63000107 ...,   0.           1.           0.        ]
 [ 18.85000038  18.05999947  18.68000031 ...,   0.           0.           0.        ]
 [ 36.65000153  35.88999939  36.40000153 ...,   0.           0.           0.        ]]
hidden layer weight __str__ = [[  9.42434692e+02   9.37118896e+02   9.37249634e+02 ...,   9.42205444e+02
    9.29060852e+02   9.37313171e+02]
 [  9.15096191e+02   9.10079407e+02   9.10099060e+02 ...,   9.15004333e+02
    9.02557251e+02   9.10014893e+02]
 [  9.29089661e+02   9.23910583e+02   9.23980042e+02 ...,   9.28754456e+02
    9.15734192e+02   9.23927551e+02]
 ..., 
 [ -1.55397624e-01   5.13047241e-02  -1.01353332e-01 ...,  -2.09151357e-01
   -2.30178908e-02   2.11653672e-02]
 [ -2.79927831e-02  -1.39014721e-01   5.01926802e-02 ...,   1.06141582e-01
    2.20231503e-01  -1.93894833e-01]
 [ -2.02077642e-01  -5.28923236e-02  -2.25870714e-01 ...,  -9.63548869e-02
    4.37522978e-02   2.13556841e-01]]
hidden layer input __str__ = [[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 ..., 
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]]
hidden layer weight __str__ = [[  2.20971644e-01   2.68182665e-01   1.79032117e-01 ...,  -1.42496407e-01
    2.52357751e-01   1.04782619e-02]
 [ -1.57890506e-02   8.03328007e-02   3.94235961e-02 ...,  -1.46802604e-01
   -9.18160826e-02   7.46842176e-02]
 [ -9.85070225e-03  -1.59118772e-01   9.11487043e-02 ...,  -1.27426431e-01
   -1.77098513e-01   1.17036752e-01]
 ..., 
 [ -1.18124679e-01  -7.00080395e-03   8.60277861e-02 ...,   5.87549880e-02
    2.09990919e-01   1.02548808e-01]
 [  2.80610733e-02  -1.13731325e-01  -2.08041459e-01 ...,   2.07085162e-01
    2.10773572e-02   1.05052345e-01]
 [  6.15737811e-02  -4.04242314e-02   2.76199616e-02 ...,   2.12645084e-01
   -5.60790449e-02   2.38036737e-05]]
hidden layer input __str__ = [[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 ..., 
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]]
hidden layer weight __str__ = [[-0.08188033  0.35473466  0.16657592 ..., -0.1260131   0.00434702
   0.32256085]
 [-0.18062061  0.37562442 -0.26837903 ...,  0.16162801  0.32392764
  -0.24518812]
 [ 0.2880756   0.25551626 -0.22080377 ...,  0.34027866  0.31578022
  -0.12841369]
 ..., 
 [ 0.35981867 -0.24354234  0.24542828 ..., -0.24827343  0.16716523
   0.31223059]
 [ 0.17080283  0.26859909  0.09803617 ..., -0.20598492 -0.11435243
   0.0041694 ]
 [ 0.21534431  0.22515434  0.27585247 ...,  0.03500938  0.34929749
  -0.06157932]]
logistic input __str__ = [[  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.98762151e-04 ...,   1.00000000e+00
    1.87955948e-03   1.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.98762151e-04 ...,   1.00000000e+00
    1.87955948e-03   1.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.98762151e-04 ...,   1.00000000e+00
    1.87955948e-03   1.00000000e+00]
 ..., 
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.98762151e-04 ...,   1.00000000e+00
    1.87955948e-03   1.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.98762151e-04 ...,   1.00000000e+00
    1.87955948e-03   1.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.98762151e-04 ...,   1.00000000e+00
    1.87955948e-03   1.00000000e+00]]
output predictions are all identical
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden outputs must be saturated. For example if hidden layer activation function is sigmoid and pre-activation values are relatively high, say 100, hidden layers saturated to sigmoid(100) = 1 or sigmoid(-100) = 0.

What you should do?

1-) Check initialization procedure. I haven't use the DBN code that you mention but probably they have implemeted initialiation correctly. Initialization must be something like;

$ \sqrt{4}/ \sqrt{visibleSize+hiddenSize} $

With this type initialization, pre-activation function fluctuates around '0'. This eliminates the problem of saturating at the beginning of training and also increases speed of convergence.

2-) feature normalization is another problem. be sure that your input has 0 mean and and unit variance. Relatively high values of inputs also cause to saturated hidden units.